# Wird hier "veranlasst" im Sinne von "angewandt" benutzt?

Tags: meaning, adjective

Der Arztbrief gibt einen zusammenfassenden Überblick über den Status des Patienten bei der Entlassung, einen Rückblick über den Krankheitsverlauf, die veranlasste Therapie, eine Interpretation des Geschehens zum Krankheitsverlauf im speziellen Fall, Informationen zur Klassifizierung der Erkrankung nach ICD, OPS, ICF und ggf. auch DRG und Empfehlungen zur Fortführung der Therapie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Verwendung des Wortes "veranlassen" bezieht sich darauf, dass der Arzt zwar die Entscheidung für eine Therapiemaßnahme trifft, diese aber nicht notwendigerweise selbst durchführt. "Veranlassen" trifft sowohl zu, wenn die Therapie vom Patienten selbst durchgeführt werden muss (z.B. Medikamenteneinnahme) als auch wenn sie durch den Arzt (z.B. Operation) oder einen Dritten (z.B. Krankengymnastik) erfolgt.

Answer (score 6):

Ein kleiner Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern ist, dass das Veranlassen sozusagen eine Aufforderung ist, etwas zu tun. Angewandt würde dann heißen, dass die veranlasste Therapie dann auch tatsächlich umgesetzt wurde.

Also streng genommen haben sie nicht die gleiche Bedeutung, ich hoffe jedoch, dass in den meisten Fällen die veranlasste Therapie auch angewendet wird :D